# Reading a text file in color

Tags: text, colors, programmers-notepad

I have a program that posts messages in different colors, eg: GREEN for info, RED for errors, YELLOW for warnings. 
When I print them into a file, I see the codes for begin_color and end_color printed in ASCII.

Is there a text viewer (preferably in Linux) where I can render this codes to their appropriate colors ?

Comment: well, something like vi/vim might interpret them (but you must have color enabled in your vim.rc or similar), adn they have to be in the correct format for whatever interpreter you are using. Here's some tips for bash itself, but these won't render in vi/vim  -- http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Comment: @boffin Can you add some details? How does the output look? (what you print in file)